# Java program to find the number of occurrences of specific word in a trie

Tags: java, trie

I am making a trie data structure. I want to find the number of occurrences of specific word in that trie e.g. if the word 'similar' is coming four times in a trie, the program should give the output of that word as 4. Can someone guide me in the right direction? Here is my code of class which is telling the index of that specific word.

```
public class TST<Value> {
    private int N;       // size
    private Node root;   // root of TST

    private class Node {
        private char c;                 // character
        private Node left, mid, right;  // left, middle, and right subtries
        private Value val;              // value associated with string
    }

    // return number of key-value pairs
    public int size() {
        return N;
    }
    public boolean contains(String key) {
        return get(key) != null;
    }

    public Value get(String key) {
        if (key == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        if (key.length() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("key must have length >= 1");
        Node x = get(root, key, 0);
        if (x == null) return null;
        return x.val;
    }

    // return subtrie corresponding to given key
    private Node get(Node x, String key, int d) {
        if (key == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        if (key.length() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("key must have length >= 1");
        if (x == null) return null;
        char c = key.charAt(d);
        if      (c < x.c)              return get(x.left,  key, d);
        else if (c > x.c)              return get(x.right, key, d);
        else if (d < key.length() - 1) return get(x.mid,   key, d+1);
        else                           return x;
    }
public void put(String s, Value val) {
        if (!contains(s)) N++;
        root = put(root, s, val, 0);
    }

    private Node put(Node x, String s, Value val, int d) {
        char c = s.charAt(d);
        if (x == null) {
            x = new Node();
            x.c = c;
        }
        if      (c < x.c)             x.left  = put(x.left,  s, val, d);
        else if (c > x.c)             x.right = put(x.right, s, val, d);
        else if (d < s.length() - 1)  x.mid   = put(x.mid,   s, val, d+1);
        else                          x.val   = val;
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean a **tree** data structure?

Comment: no. trie data structure